# According to or depending on?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> The user's view of the computer varies **according to/depending on** the interface being used.

What is the difference between **according to** and **depending on** in this sentence?

Comment: I would prefer to use **depending on** myself.

Comment: VanechikSpace, to avoid answerers "reinventing the wheel", please edit your question (using the "Edit" button under the question) to include what you already know about the two terms, and if possible, more precisely where your concern lies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OP's context, ***according to*** and ***depending [up]on*** mean exactly the same. But the second version has [become much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=varies%20according%20to%2Cvaries%20depending%20on%2Cvaries%20depending%20upon&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvaries%20according%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvaries%20depending%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvaries%20depending%20upon%3B%2Cc0) in recent decades, so for a *learner*, the best advice is to accept *varies according to...* as "valid", but always use *varies **depending on*** yourself.

[image]

You'll also encounter *varies **in accord with, ...in accordance with, ...dependent on, ...dependant on, dependent upon, ...dependant upon*** - all of which also mean the same thing, but are less common. Again, just accept those forms if you encounter them, but don't use them yourself.